# What's the CONFIG_SYS_EXTRA_OPTIONS in u-boot?

Tags: u-boot

I don't understand below configuration in the configuration file in the u-boot.

```
CONFIG_SYS_EXTRA_OPTIONS="SYS_SDRAM_SIZE=0x20000000"
```

It seems like setting DRAM size in the u-boot code. 
But, I can't find the code which uses this configuration.

If you know this configuration how to work, please let me know.

Comment: Are you using the device tree to set up the memory size, what's the version of uboot your using?

Comment: Are you using CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_SIZE in your configuration as well?

Comment: Yes, I found CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_SIZE from the code which use the configuration to get sdram size. I think that the prefix CONFIG_ is attached at the compile time.

Comment: Yes, CONFIGURATIONs are macro replacement in the background so it sets at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The little history about the configuration, earlier board.cfg is used prior to kconfig.
boards.cfg was the main database that contained ARCH, CPU, etc. This is moved to kconfig in that options field of boards.cfg was converted as

```
 Options     ->  CONFIG_SYS_EXTRA_OPTIONS defined by Kconfig
```

CONFIG_SYS_EXTRA_OPTIONS is defined as an extra option, also this can be set using CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_SIZE as well.

After building the uboot go to the build dir and the corresponding board dir and you can simply grep for the string and you can see the sdram size.

---

From the [README.kconfig](https://github.com/utilite-computer/u-boot/blob/1fb8d7933924aa5deb7e722d64c1d9fc7f0b2b82/doc/README.kconfig#L143)

> - The option field of boards.cfg, which was used for the pre-Kconfig   configuration, moved to CONFIG_SYS_EXTRA_OPTIONS verbatim now.   Board
>     maintainers are expected to implement proper Kconfig options   and
>     switch over to them.  Eventually CONFIG_SYS_EXTRA_OPTIONS will go
>     away.   CONFIG_SYS_EXTRA_OPTIONS should not be used for new boards.